# how to fix it ''Given input size: (64x176x64). Calculated output size: (64x1x0). Output size is too small''

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I am trying to use colab to train a segdecNet  which looks like this,github https://github.com/mengcius/Surface-Defect-Detection

```
        # SE layers
        self.fc1 = nn.Conv2d(64, 64//16, kernel_size=1)
        self.fc2 = nn.Conv2d(64//16, 64, kernel_size=1)    

        self.layer4 = nn.Sequential(
                            nn.Conv2d(64, 1024, 15, stride=1, padding=7),
                            nn.BatchNorm2d(1024),
                            nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
                        )

        self.layer5 = nn.Sequential(
                            nn.Conv2d(1024, 1, 1),
                            nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
                        )


        if init_weights == True:
            pass

    def forward(self, x):
        x1 = self.layer1(x)
        x2 = self.layer2(x1)
        x3 = self.layer3(x2)

        # Squeeze
        w = F.avg_pool2d(x3, x3.size(2))
        w = F.relu(self.fc1(w))
        w = torch.sigmoid(self.fc2(w))
        # Excitation
        x3 = x3 * w

        x4 = self.layer4(x3)
        x5 = self.layer5(x4)
        # print('x:', x4.shape, x5.shape) 

        return {"f":x4, "seg":x5}
```

I get this error:

```
Namespace(b1=0.5, b2=0.999, batch_size=2, begin_epoch=0, cuda=True, end_epoch=101, gpu_num=1, img_height=1408, img_width=512, lr=0.0001, need_save=True, need_test=True, save_interval=10, test_interval=10, worker_num=4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_segment.py", line 140, in <module>
    rst = segment_net(img)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 550, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/content/models.py", line 87, in forward
    w = F.avg_pool2d(x3, x3.size(2))
RuntimeError: Given input size: (64x176x64). Calculated output size: (64x1x0). Output size is too small
```

I'm guessing I'm making a mistake in my channel size or pooling size but i don't know how to fix it.i did't change the dataset in github,but i got error
i try to change torch1.2 it work.but i want to know if i did't change torch how can i fix my code

Answer (score 0):

Your average pool operation causes your input to diminish into a scalar.

```
w = F.avg_pool2d(x3, x3.size(2))
```

Reason why this is happening is that the second parameter of average pool operation is decides how many times smaller the output dimensions will be. You are basically dividing your size with itself. Try using a smaller number (like 2) instead.

```
w = F.avg_pool2d(x3, 2)
```

Edit:

Based on the error you got as

```
x3 = x3 * w RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (32) must 
match the size of tensor b (16) at non-singleton 
dimension 3
```

I would recommend not using the average pooling at all. Just try to comment it out all together. Because it seems that you should match the size of the x3 tensor.

Comment: but when i try using a smaller number (like 2) instead,i shows                                                     
x3 = x3 * w
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (32) must match the size of tensor b (16) at non-singleton dimension 3